# BLE: Bonding initiated with already bonded device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I have two BLE devices configured to work as peripheral(s) with simple static pass pairing program and Android phone as client.
1) peripheral_1 address = 0xCECECECECE with static passkey 123456, Device name = Garden, appearance = generic tag.
2) peripheral_2 address = 0xC1C1C1C1C1 with static passkey 123456, Device name = Garden, appearance = generic tag.
Both peripherals IO configured as display only.

I try to connect to peripheral_1 through nrfConnect app, I get pop-up to feed passkey, after giving correct passkey the devices are bonded and all good.
repeated the same procedure with peripheral_2 and all good as well.

Now the real problem comes in. After disconnecting with peripheral_2, I tried to connect to peripheral_1, I get pop again to feed in passkey for already bonded device, why?
Also, after feeding in the passkey I can't read any of the characteristics values unless I disconnect and re-connect to peripheral_1. Why?

Now I repeat with peripheral_2 and I see the same behaviour(client asks to feed in passkey again).

I believe the STK/LTK should be uniquely generated based on the BT address and store in client's database.

Suppose if I change the appearance of one of the peripheral to "unknown" then I see the client does not ask for passkey to re-enter again after bonding. Only with this combination 
appearance it works("unknown" vs "").
Any inputs, suggestions are greatly appreciated.